# Does it make sense to use Gaussian Naive Bayes for a single feature?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, scikit-learn, naive-bayes

I understand that 'Naive' Bayes refers to the approach where all the features are assumed to be independent. But I want to evaluate the performance of each feature individually before I combine all of them and use them for prediction.

Can I still use [sklearn's implementation of Gaussian Naive Bayes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB) for making predictions using a single feature for this?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that 'Naive' Bayes refers to the approach where all the
> features are assumed to be independent.

Features are assumed to be *conditionally* independent given class label. And, you can fit Gaussian (or any other) Naive Bayes using one feature, in which it's not forced to be Naive any more.